# What have to happen with database connection after hibernate.c3p0.timeout is reached?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat

In docs, I've read the next:

> Seconds a Connection can remain pooled but unused before being
>   discarded. Zero means idle connections never expire.

So, if I understand right, after connection reached `hibernate.c3p0.timeout` it has to be removed from the pool and physical connection to a database have to be closed too? Or not?

I am monitoring all connections by the MySQL Workbench Client Connections and see that created connections never expired. Furthermore, amount of created connections is bigger than I set by `hibernate.c3p0.max_size` parameter. Also, after some amount of time connections reset their time value to 0 in Client Connection Window. So that mean that they were checked\used in the case when they actually didn't use at that moment. Why did that happen? Anyway, it works well with `hibernate.c3p0.min_size` parameter, because creates the right amount of connections every time. I see right configuration values in Tomcat logs as well. I experimented with `hibernate.connection.release_mode`, but it does not give any result.

I use HibernateTemplate from SpringORM and I have the next configuration:

**hibernate.cfg.xml**:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">jdbc:mysql://localhost/easywordweb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/easywordweb</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>

    <!--<property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">140</property>-->
    <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">140</property>--> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">9</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">3</property>
    <!--max to cache-->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>

    <!--The seconds a Connection can remain pooled but unused before being discarded. Zero means idle connections never expire. Hibernate default: 0-->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">40</property>

    <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>--> 
    <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1;</property>-->
    <!--for test, change futher-->
    <!----> 
    <!--at every connection checkin to verify that the connection is valid-->
    <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>-->
    <!--at every connection checkout to verify that the connection is valid-->
    <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property>-->
    <!--/for test, change futher-->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>


    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</property>
    <!--Number rows to be returned if no setted-->
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>

    <!--FIXING: Table "...".hibernate_sequence table not found.-->
    <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Tomcat** run with next config:

```
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getPoolManager
Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@11c5be52
[ 
    connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@87645e0f 
    [ 
        acquireIncrement -> 3, 
        acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, 
        acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, 
        autoCommitOnClose -> false, 
        automaticTestTable -> null, 
        breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false,
        checkoutTimeout -> 0, 
        connectionCustomizerClassName -> null,
        connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester,
        debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, 
        factoryClassLocation -> null, 
        forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false,
        identityToken -> valididentitytokenhere, 
        idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, 
        initialPoolSize -> 5, 
        maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, 
        maxConnectionAge -> 0, 
        maxIdleTime -> 40,
        maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, 
        maxPoolSize -> 9, 
        maxStatements -> 50, 
        maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, 
        minPoolSize -> 5, 
        nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@82d61130 
        [ 
            description -> null, 
            driverClass -> null, 
            factoryClassLocation -> null, 
            identityToken -> valididentitytokenhere, 
            jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost/easywordweb, 
            properties -> { user=******, password=******} 
        ], 
        preferredTestQuery -> null, 
        propertyCycle -> 0, 
        statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, 
        testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, 
        testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, 
        unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, 
        usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; 
        userOverrides: {} 
    ], 
    dataSourceName -> null, 
    factoryClassLocation -> null, 
    identityToken -> valididentitytokenhere, 
    numHelperThreads -> 3 
]
```

**spring-context.xml**:

```
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="milkiv.easyword.models"/>
    <property name="configLocations">
        <value>classpath:resources/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>



    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="milkiv.easyword.service.JsonConverter"></bean>
    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/> 

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="milkiv.easyword"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.method.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
</beans>
```

I will appreciate any explanations, links and help. 
Thank's everyone in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider following. Initially min amount of connections are created. If it's not enough more connections are opened till max amount is achieved.

Now if application does not need so many connections some of them are not used - idle connections. If a connection is idle for 40 seconds (in your case) it's closed till min amount is achieved. If a connection is used from time to time (your application uses the connection) e.g. each 30 seconds the connection is never closed.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your clear answer and concept explanation.
Still, can not understand why c3p0 configuration worked incorrectly when it was defined in hibernate.cfg.xml. Anyway, I resolved this issue by moving my c3p0 configuration to the separate config file and now it is work fine.